# How do I parse a bit field in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I want to parse bit fields with PHP similar to this: `584392900608`

This number was created in Rails, with the FlagShihTzu extension. I tried several PHP classes, but I couldn't decipher them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Bitfield.php](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/28323.html) will be of help? It worked for me.